# Gradle, shadowJar: use relocate inside task

Tags: gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I have the following task:

```
task myJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = 'myJar.jar'
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    destinationDir = rootProject.libsDir
    dependsOn compileJava

    manifest.attributes('Class-Path': '../lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar')

    into '/', {
        from compileJava.destinationDir
        include 'com/myCompany/project/util/order/**',
                'com/myCompany/project/event/**',
    }
}
```

and I would like to relocate all classes from com/myCompany/project/event/** to com/myCompany/relocated/project/event/** (so that some apps using my jar and having com.myCompany.project.event package defined will avoid any possible conflicts)

I discovered that it can be done using shadow plugin and I tried to add

```
relocate 'com.myCompany.project.event.', 'com.myCompany.relocated.project.event.'
```

under this task but it doesn't seem to work.
 Does anybody know where I should add this line?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, hence just a comment, but have you tried specifying `type: ShadowJar` instead of `type: Jar`?

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by adding below plugin to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
```

After adding this plugin add below code to your build.gradle file

```
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.myCompany.project.event', 'com.myCompany.relocated.project.event'
}
```

After adding this, to ensure your ShadowJar task runs before build, add this line at the end

```
assemble.dependsOn shadowJar
```

This will ensure that shadow jar task is triggered before assemble/build task during gradle build.

On doing the Gradle build, you should see all your packages and their corresponding dependencies relocated from 'com.myCompany.project.event' to 'com.myCompany.relocated.project.event'.

For more info you can refer to [ShadowJarUserGuide](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/custom-tasks/)