# Multiple dependency versions with Gradle 5

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-shadow-plugin

I need to support 2 different versions of the same library (to support a legacy version), `es4hadoop` for Apache Spark.

- Version `6.2.2`(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10/6.2.2)
- Version `6.3.2` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10/6.3.2)

Both versions have same dependencies (scala-lang and Spark).

Not sure at all about the naming of that, but I would like something like:

```
implementation(group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-13_' + scalaVersion, version:'6.2.2') {
     exclude group: "org.scala-lang"  
}

implementation(group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-13_' + scalaVersion, version:'6.3.2') {
     exclude group: "org.scala-lang"
     relocate org.elasticsearch org.elasticsearch6 // ???
}
```

so I can use both new and old elasticsearch library, in the same project / JVM.

I know already it's possible to `relocate` lib with the `shadowJar` plugin, but is it possible to relocate a specific version?

Comment: Yes, assuming they have the same packagenames, you would need to shade/shadow one of the libraries to move the classes to a different package (and change all existing references in classes needing that version), e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060258. This is a very complex topic, so expect a lot of problems, and you need to explain in much more detail what you need to achieve to get a response.

Comment: I see this is very complicate :/ for now, I clone the lib and replace all package names by hand, it's working fine but quite dirty, curious to see there is no a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put one of the `elasticsearch-spark` dependencies into a subproject `aa2` and relocate it. Then the other subproject `aa1` can depend on `aa2`'s shadow configuration.

```gradle
// aa2/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10:6.2.2'
}

shadowJar {
    relocate "org.elasticsearch", "org.elasticsearch_v6_2_2"
}
```

```gradle
// aa1/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10:6.3.2'
    implementation project(path: ':aa2', configuration: 'shadow')
}
```

You can now declare the same class in this way:

```java
package com.github.chehsunliu.stackoverflow.q56332118;

import org.elasticsearch.spark.cfg.SparkSettings;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(SparkSettings.class);
    System.out.println(org.elasticsearch_v6_2_2.spark.cfg.SparkSettings.class);
  }
}
```

However, you should pay more attention to their transitive dependencies. You might also need to relocate them to make the direct dependencies work normally. Sometimes I will decompress the output JAR file and investigate these `.class` files to ensure the resolution correctness.

### References

- **Minimal project:** https://github.com/chehsunliu/stackoverflow/tree/main/a.2021-08-03.gradle.56332118
- **Decompiler** https://java-decompiler.github.io/